# Change Icon of lightning-accordion-section component in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to change the default "chevron" icon used for all sections and levels with  Plus and Minus icons respectively. Is there any standard way by which I can achieve this? Following is the sample code of my template.

```
<template>
    <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open
                         active-section-name={activeSections}>
        <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
            <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
            <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open>
                <lightning-accordion-section name="d" label="Accordion Title D">Content D</lightning-accordion-section>
                <lightning-accordion-section name="e" label="Accordion Title E">Content E</lightning-accordion-section>
                <lightning-accordion-section name="f" label="Accordion Title F">Content F</lightning-accordion-section>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the Shadow DOM and the way that CSS works in LWC.

Currently developers do not have a way to override/customize CSS that is derived from Base Components. Salesforce team is working on giving developers more options.

Even in LWC Accordion's [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-accordion/specification) there isn't any attribute called `icon-name.`

If you need greater control than what's allowed by the component, you'll need to write your own instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I knew it was not possible in LWC but I tried my luck by posting this question.

Comment: @RahulPawar Ok. Please do upvote & mark as Best Answer if you feel

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the Aura page dragged on the LWC Component.

1. Create an Aura Component and Drag on the LWC Component.

   ```
   `<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:html tag="style">
        .slds-accordion__summary-action-icon {
          --b: 5px;
          width: 15px;
          aspect-ratio: 1;
          border: 0px solid #00000005;
          background: conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b),#fff 90deg,#000000 0) calc(106% + var(--b)/2) calc(83% + var(--b)/2)/ calc(51% + var(--b)) calc(48% + var(--b));
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .slds-is-open>.slds-accordion__summary .slds-accordion__summary-action-icon{
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            --b: 5px;
            width: 15px;
            aspect-ratio: 1;
            border: 0px solid #00000005;
            background: conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b),#fff 90deg,#000000 0) calc(106% + var(--b)/2) calc(83% + var(--b)/2)/ calc(124% + var(--b)) calc(46% + var(--b));
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </aura:HTML>
    </aura:component>`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using extra Aura component, you can add the above-mentioned css code to the static CSS resource:

```
.slds-accordion__summary-action-icon {
    --b: 5px;
    width: 15px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border: 0px solid #00000005;
    background: conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b),#0000 90deg,#000000 0) calc(106% + var(--b)/2) calc(83% + var(--b)/2)/ calc(51% + var(--b)) calc(48% + var(--b));
    display: inline-block;
}

.slds-accordion__summary-action-icon>g {
    display: none;
}

.slds-is-open>.slds-accordion__summary .slds-accordion__summary-action-icon{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    --b: 5px;
    width: 15px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border: 0px solid #00000005;
    background: conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b),#0000 90deg,#000000 0) calc(106% + var(--b)/2) calc(83% + var(--b)/2)/ calc(124% + var(--b)) calc(46% + var(--b));
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Import it into your LWC:

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import css from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/css';

loadStyles() {
    loadStyle(this, css + '/your_css_file.css');
}
```

Two things fixed:

- original accordion icon is hidden
- new icon background is transparent