Change the icon for the lightning-accordion in LWC
I am trying to replace the arrow sign in the lwc accordion with a plus when opened and a minus when closed.
A previous question, indicates that we can modify using CSS, but it is not working for me and the question is old, so not sure if it still is true. Does anyone know if it this is even possible?

You can custom build your own accordion using the lightning design system library https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/

Can you please share the code which you have tried?

Hi @TusharJadav,   I copied the code given in the last answer of the mentioned pervious question(https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293889/change-icon-of-lightning-accordion-section-component-in-lwc) , but it is not working for me.

I tried the accordion code given in the Lightning Design System (LDS) documentation and have slightly modified it to make the ‘add symbol’ appear.
Notice the use of  tag which is calling the ‘_slds’ folder and which is accessing the ‘add symbol’. Similary, I have added the code to make the minus sign appear which is 'erectwindow symbol'. Furthermore, these symbols can be toggled using a boolean variable controlled in JS.
I have utilised the SLDS Button variant to make the Accordion header work like a button.
HTML
<ul class="slds-accordion">
   <li class="slds-accordion__list-item">
      <section class="slds-accordion__section slds-is-open">
         <div class="slds-accordion__summary">
            <h2 class="slds-accordion__summary-heading">
               <button class="slds-button slds-button_reset slds-accordion__summary-action" aria-controls="referenceId-42" aria-expanded="true" title="Accordion summary" >
                  <svg class="slds-accordion__summary-action-icon slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
        <!—-Putting the Add Symbol—->
                     <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#add"></use>
                  </svg>
        <!—-Using Lightning Button for Accordion Header—->
                  <lightning-button variant="base" label="Accordion A" title="Accordion A" onclick={handleButtonClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small" >
                 </lightning-button>
               </button>
            </h2>
         </div>
         <template lwc:if={boolShowSectionA}>
            <div class="slds-accordion__content" id="referenceId-42">
               <p>     Accordion details - A</p>
            </div>
         </template>
      </section>
   </li>
  <li class="slds-accordion__list-item">
   <section class="slds-accordion__section">
      <div class="slds-accordion__summary">
         <h2 class="slds-accordion__summary-heading">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_reset slds-accordion__summary-action" aria-controls="referenceId-43" aria-expanded="false" title="Accordion summary">
               <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-picklist_type slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" title="List icon">
                  <svg class=" slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use  xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#erect_window"></use>
                  </svg>
               </span>
               <span class="slds-accordion__summary-content">Accordion B</span>
            </button>
         </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-accordion__content" id="referenceId-43">Accordion details - B</div>
   </section>
 </li>
</ul>

Javascript
 import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class CustomAccordionLWC extends LightningElement {
    boolShowSectionA;
 
    handleButtonClick(){
        this.boolShowSectionA = true;
    }
}


This is how the accordion appears

To know more about the LDS Accordion, please refer this link
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/
To know more about icons, please refer this link
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility
